# No module error found while importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import panda in python script .

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

But I am getting below error :

```
Error from Scripts is : Script failed to run: 
Error: [Traceback (most recent call last):
   
   File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
] (2604) (2603)
```

This python script I am using in Cortex XSOAR (demisto).

I have to sort values in columns in one table. Google results shows that have to use pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.  Hence, using this.

Please help me on fixing error with pandas module import or suggest me if there is any other way I can sort table values based on 1 column i.e integer values

Thanks in advance ,
NVP

Comment: Are you sure pandas is installed? What output does "pip list" (or conda list if you're using conda) give?

Comment: you need to install pandas in order to import and use it. It is not standard python library

Answer (score 0):

Did you install pandas ?

py -m pip install pandas

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check where you installed pandas and use sys to append that path to your code.

For example:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\users\NVP\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages')
```

Answer (score 0):

Every script/integration in XSOAR runs on a docker image which you can set in the script/integration settings so probably the docker image you are using in the script/integration does not include the pandas library

For more info see [xsoar.pan.dev](https://xsoar.pan.dev)